# Anyone using Captcha for the guest checkout?

Tags: magento2, captcha, guest-checkout

Anyone using Captcha for the **Guest checkout** in Magento 2? If yes, which Captcha menthod you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any Extension for checkout. After installing extension and at the time of configuring at checkout make sure to add Valid class that helps to show captcha.

I think Mageplaza extension is good

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the best solution is to use default magento recaptcha for guest checkout. You can reach this by the same way as magento added recaptcha to checkout login form (entry point: `vendor/msp/recaptcha/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`).